# Ubuntu 18.04/i3wm - No low battery notifications

Tags: gnome, power-management, battery, notification

I'm trying to debug why I'm not receiving any low power notifications on my Ubuntu 18 laptop running i3wm. As I understand it, `gnome-settings-daemon`is responsible for sending these notifications. I've done the following:

- Set my critical percentage to 10 via `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 10`.
- Confirmed the `gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-power` process is running.
- Confirmed I'm capable of receiving notifications through other means (such as Spotify, notify-send, etc.).

Despite this, I still appear to not be receiving notifications when I cross this threshold. Am I missing something? Thanks!